# How applications are installed in TEE and REE

Tags: cryptography, embedded-system, tee

I am trying to understand the difference between the TEE (Trusted Execution Environment) and REE (Rich Execution Environment) in an electronic component. I understand that for security reasons, there is a TEE environment. I want to understand how one can manage to install an application (a Trusted Application) in TEE and a normal application in REE. That is, how do we instruct the application to install in a specific environment.

I am newbie to security in electronic components. I will be really happy if I can get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The installation of TEE application purely depends on the TEE that you choose. There are so many TEE vendors in the market. General methods of TEE application installation are

1. Build the TEE application statically in the TEE itself.
2. Install the TEE application from the REE file system. There are commands available to install these applications to secure memory from TEE